# Average of a Lebesgue Measurable Function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Say I define an indicator function over a set E and demand that this function have an average of 1/2.  It is apparently sufficient to ask that the measure m(E) = 1/2.  Why is this?  I understood Ave(f) to be integral(f)/m(E) which if I calculated correctly would give a value of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the total mass of $m$. That is, if $m$ is a finite measure on a space $X$, i.e. $m(X)<\infty$, and $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is a bounded measurable function, then we can define the $m$-average of $f$ as
$$
  \mathrm{A}f :=\frac1{m(X)}\int_X f\mathrm dm.
$$
In case $f = 1_E$ is an indicator function, we clearly have $\mathrm Af = m(E)/m(X)$, so that in general you have to have $m(E) = \frac12 m(X)$ to assure that $\mathrm A1_E = \frac12$.

Comment: So it happens in this case that since m(X) is just 1 as we are integrating over [0,1] and since our indicator function is simply 1 all that is left to add to other value of the average is m(E) and so we set it as desired?

Comment: @user70944: in case you're dealing with probability spaces, that is $m(X) = 1$, the average is exactly the integral, so yes.

Comment: By dealing with probability spaces do you mean dealing with a space for which the domain of our function is [0,1]?  The context of where this question comes from does not refer to probability spaces though I could see how the situation might be analogous.  Thank you!

Comment: @user70944: no, a bit more general as I wrote: a measure space $(X,\Sigma,m)$ is called a probability space if $m(X) = 1$

Comment: I see!  And our case where f: [0,1] ---> {0,1} satisfies this.  Thank you.

Comment: Can we not replace bounded by Lebesgue integrable here?

Comment: @Shahab Lebesgue integrable means what?

Comment: I mean the general theory of Lebesgue integration on a measure space: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration

Comment: You can define $m$-average anyway you want to. Whom am I to stop you from that?

Comment: Of course we can . But I simply asked as to whether that is an equivalent definition or not. It boils down to if bounded+measurable is the same as lebesgue integrable on a finite measure space. I think bounded+measurable implies integrable here but am not sure about the converse.

Comment: Is $x^{-\frac12}$ lebesgue integrable on $(0,1]$? @Shahab

Comment: Yes...but it isnt bounded. Ok. (The reason I had asked about the generalized definition was in the context of the definition of expected value)